# dropdown onclick function call to controller function not returning data

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I want to call to controller function by dropdown onclick.but its not called and returne data to view.
here This is my view.

```
<div class="dropdown">    
<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select Department
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="javascript:void()" onclick="store()">Store</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void()" onclick="accounts()">Accounts</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

This is my controller

```
<?php
public function store() {
        $deptid=1;
        $data['store_table'] = $this->report->get_datatables($deptid);
        $data['reporttitle'] ="Store Employee";
        $this->load->view('report/emp_report_view',$data);
?>
```

Comment: Edit question and show `store()` and `accounts()` functions.

Comment: store() and accounts() function in controller.i can't call direct controller function from view?

Comment: Those are presented as javascript functions here. What is JS code? Do you want to load part of page or redirect to other page?

Comment: This is my model.which call by controller. function get_datatables($deptid)
 {
  $query = $this->db->get_where('employee', array('deptid' => $deptid));
  return $query->result();
 }

Comment: I tried call to store() by dropdown onclick.where store() function define in controller.is it possible?

Comment: Code you have there is trying to call JS functions NOT php functions/methods. I need to ask again: do you want to load some part of view on same page or your intention is to redirect to other page?